# Can all the commands provided in TABLELIST package be used for Gridplus 2 tablelist

Tags: tcl

I was experimenting with the tablelist option in Gridplus 2. I had to embed windows in cells to get check boxes and radio buttons in my table, so while trying to get the work done i tried to get the cell index and found out it gives me an error when i used the command

```
.mytablelist cellindex x,y
```

where x - row and y-column. Then I tried out other cell commands like **cellcget** and **cellselection** and every command gave me an error saying

```
bad command "cellcget": must be configure, cget, instate, state, or identify
```

I followed the command syntax as given in [table list documentation](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#cellcget) by Dr.Csada Nemethi. So can anyone clarify if it is my mistake or if Gridplus 2 does not support all the commands available for the actual tablelist package.

Comment: What does `winfo class .mytablelist` report?

Comment: winfo class .maytablelist  reports 'Tframe '

Comment: Then it's a ttk::frame, and so only responds to the methods described for that class (not many; ttk::frame is pretty trivial after all). You probably need to use a different widget name, or create it in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GRIDPLUS2 the actual name of the tablelist widget will be ".mytablelist.tablelist" - Try...

```
.mytablelist.tablelist cellindex x,y
```

...GRIDPLUS2 widget naming details can be found in the documentation at:-

http://www.satisoft.com/tcltk/gridplus2/reference.html#names

Best Regards,

=Adrian=